# How to stop EF4.1 Code-First to create Culstered index for the entity PK

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

With the following simple entity class, EF4.1 Code-First will create Clustered Index for the PK `UserId` column when intializing the database.

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int AppId  { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

For performance sake, my design goals is to keep the generated `Users` table physical Clustered according to the `AppId` coulmn not to the PK.

On my Initializer class I've tried to manually drop the autogenerated PK clustered index and create whatever clustered index I need, but no clue here to predict the autogenerated name `PK__Users__25518C17` for the index!

I'm new to Code-First world, and really don't know if there's any workaround for my design goals.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to predict name of auto generated index. You just need to select name of the index. For SQL server you can use query like:

```
SELECT I.Name
FROM sys.indexes AS I
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T ON
    I.object_Id = T.object_Id
WHERE I.is_primary_key = 1 
    AND T.Name = 'Users'
```

Once you get the name in your custom initializer you can alter old index and create a new one.

Comment: Many thanks, this helped me alot to go on with my approach. but later I learned that I have to drop/recreate every index/relation to get the User table clusterd on the AppId.

Comment: Very painful approach in real world applications!!     Without annotations like [Key(NonClustered)] or [Index(Clustered)] and without custom Conventions, designing the database-first then code-first is my way to go!  still open for suggestions or hints. Thanks once more.

Comment: Hossam, I actually think you've come to the right conclusion. DB generation is really only intended for indescriminate schemas on simple applications that can be A) generated to any datasource - even a configurable one & B) are simple. Because not all data storage systems even know what a clustered index is, EF probably won't even deal with it... that means it is definitely time for you to manage your own schema. Using a DB project will mean you can import a generated DB and tweak it very easily.