# Entity Framework Code-First - Define the Non-clustered key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I Have defined an entity class with a key, but I don,t want that key be cluster because I have another
cluster index in my entity, but I received an error when I add an Index attribute to my model,

Can anybody tell me that how can I define a **Non-Clustered Key**????

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please spare a minute to read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), you will not get a good feedback if not providing enough information about your problem (the error message, the code, the environment, etc)..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create non clustered index on primary key entity framework 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475545/create-non-clustered-index-on-primary-key-entity-framework-6-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is still not possible to create non-clustered primary key fields as part of your code first configuration.

However, if you are using **migrations** or are in a position where you are able to, see the following Entity Framework work item that goes through a solution using **code first migrations** (as well as the thinking behind no direct code first support):

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/614

This related question has some information as well: [EF CodeFirst create non-clustered primary key index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813462/ef-codefirst-create-non-clustered-primary-key-index). It is for EF 4.1 but still relevant to EF 6.

Comment: the link you gave specified that it is possible with additional migration and specifying the [clustered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn218420%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to false, but yeah u're right, no direct code first..

Comment: Yep - the Entity Framework work item link is pretty good. Interestingly it links off to http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20January%2010%2c%202013 which are minutes from Entity Framework design meetings. I wasn't aware these were made publicly available but will be reading through them from now on. May be of interest to you (incase you didn't know about it either?) as I often see your name around Entity Framework questions.

Comment: yup didn't know too, I think they can fix the clustered thing quickly, but keep it on hold because it will impact another commercial product..

Comment: @YuliamChandra thanx for your hints, it was useful, but would you tell me that where can i find **code first migrations** on the other word: where I must write statements described in the link?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend moving to code first migrations just to support non-clustered primary keys. Its a reasonably complex subject with a few lumpy bits on the learning curve along the way. By the sound of your question you aren't using Drop/Create database initialisers so I would just manually edit the table schema and recreate the pk as non-clustered.