# Convert and modify a model field as an DataColumn object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3 I would like to access at database creation time the model fields as if they were objects of DataColumn class, so that I could then modify the [auto-increment setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement.aspx) and store it back.

My primary target is to disable the auto-incrementing (identity setting) on the primary key of a model using code first approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might what you need

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MyID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for! A little shorter version: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]