# Database seeding only works for one model, not a second

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm seeding test data into two models, `Author` and `Post`. The seeding works for `Author`, but seems to fail silently for `Post`.

**Edit:** I think I've found the source of the issue. I've caught the exception, and the message is

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table `Post` when `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to OFF.

There may be a workaround for this in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896047/how-to-turn-on-identity-insert-in-net-core), but I was wondering if anyone has any ideas why this occurs? Is this because we shouldn't manually set the value of the primary key?

I am loosing following [this Microsoft Docs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), but using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1. The basic strategy is that the `Main()` method in the `Program` class calls `DbInitializer.Initialize()`, which seeds the data if there are no `Authors` in the context.

I have stepped over the `DbInitializer` class, and the code goes through the same process for both models, looping through the seeded array, adding it to the context and (apparently) saving changes. However, while the `Author` database fields are populated with seed data, the `Post` fields are not.

Edit: While stepping through and inspecting the generated context, sometimes the `Author` fields have strange `ID` values and sometimes the `Post` fields have strange `ID` values :-2147492647, -2147492646, etc... I have tried to change `PostID` to `ID` on the off chance that that caused the issue, but the same issue occurs with that field name.

My second thought is wondering whether this has something to do with the many-to-one relationship between Post and Author. However, I've tried to seed `Post` data with only the `Title` field (so excluding the foreign key `AuthorID`), and that hasn't made a difference. I'm new to ASP.NET so my hope is that I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for any direction.

**MyWebsiteContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyWebsite.Models;

namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class MyWebsiteContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyWebsiteContext (DbContextOptions<MyWebsiteContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<MyWebsite.Models.Author> Author { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MyWebsite.Models.Post> Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DbInitializer.cs**

```
using MyWebsite.Models;

namespace MyWebsite.Data
{
    public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(MyWebsiteContext context)
        {
            // Look for any authors; if none, seed DB.
            if (context.Author.Any())
            {
                return; // DB has already been seeded.
            }

            var authors = new Author[]
            {
                new Author{ FirstName="Terry",LastName="Pratchett",SignUpDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-04-01")},
                new Author{ FirstName="Neil",LastName="Gaiman",SignUpDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-03-02")},
            };

            foreach (Author a in authors)
            {
                context.Author.Add(a);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var posts = new Post[]
            {
                new Post{PostID=1,Title="Title of post 1"},
                new Post{PostID=2,Title="Title of post 2"},
                new Post{PostID=3,Title="Title of post 3"},
            };
            foreach (Post p in posts)
            {
                context.Post.Add(p);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyWebsite.Data;
using MyWebsite.Models;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyWebsiteContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

**Post.cs**

```
namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class Post   // Post entity is dependent on Author class
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; } // primary key
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int AuthorID { get; set; } // foreign key
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Author.cs**

```
namespace MyWebsite.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime SignUpDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if it work. I have this same issue since I working with seeding relational entity. My recommend is try to put try catch in your code to see if it there any exception

In your Program.cs

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
  var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
  SeedData.Initialize(services).Wait();
}
```

Then seed like this

```
public static async Task Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
  using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
            {
                if (!context.Posts.Any())
                {
                    post.Comments = comments;

                    await SeedPost(context);
                }
            }
}
```

You can see that my Post entity have list of comments so I will also assign list of comment into Post object then seed in once go

You can view my full code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/SeedData.cs)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I didn't realize that an exception was being generated. (It was being caught with my original code but I didn't notice that happening.) That led me to the answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first time it performs the SaveChange() operation successfully, but the second time it takes an error to add posts due to the lack of a foreign key of author, and the operation is not performed.
Always use one SaveChange!

You must add foreign key AuthorId to Post Model or map Author Object to Post.Author object to create relation

```cs
 public static void Initialize(MyWebsiteContext context)
        {
            // Look for any authors; if none, seed DB.
            if (context.Author.Any())
            {
                return; // DB has already been seeded.
            }

            var authors = new Author[]
            {
                new Author{ FirstName="Terry",LastName="Pratchett",SignUpDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-04-01")},
                new Author{ FirstName="Neil",LastName="Gaiman",SignUpDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-03-02")},
            };

            foreach (Author a in authors)
            {
                context.Author.Add(a);
            }

            var posts = new Post[]
            {
                new Post{PostID=1,Title="Title of post 1" ,Author = authors[0] },
                new Post{PostID=2,Title="Title of post 2" ,Author = authors[0]},
                new Post{PostID=3,Title="Title of post 3" ,Author = authors[0]},
            };
            foreach (Post p in posts)
            {
                context.Post.Add(p);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and showing me how to map `Author` to `Post.Author`! It looks like I had to a) map `Author` to `Post.Author`, and b) remove the `PostID` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed to be fixed in the original code:

1. The definition of `PostID` during seeding. The two options are either a) remove that definition, or b) explicitly turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` in SQL Server. The second method is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896047/how-to-turn-on-identity-insert-in-net-core), but for my purposes, simply removing the definition worked.
2. Mapping the `Author` object to `Post.Author`. Simply calling `new Post{Title="Title of post 1"}` was not sufficient; specifying the `Author` was required.

Relevant `DbInitializer` segment:

```
            var posts = new Post[]
            {
                new Post{Title = "Title of post 1", Author = authors[0]},
                new Post{Title = "Title of post 2", Author = authors[0]},
                new Post{Title = "Title of post 3", Author = authors[1]},
            };
```

Thanks for all the help.