# How to "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON" on Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create an object by manually inserting the primary key, but it's not possible the way I have it. I tried to put the `ExecuteSqlCommand()` but it doesn't exist.

I check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973327/13954475 but that didn't solve my problem.

I have this:

```
public void CreateYear(int yearId)
{
        try 
        {
            Year year = new Year();
            year.YearId = yearId;
            year.YearAcademic = yearId.ToString() + "/" + (yearId + 1).ToString();
            year.IsActive = false;

            _context.Database.ExecuteSql($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Years ON");
            _context.Years.Add(year);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _context.Database.ExecuteSql($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Years OFF");

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
            
}
```

I also tried with `ExecuteSqlRaw` and others.

Comment: Best solution : **do not** try to insert the identity value - let the database handle that for you (that's what it's intended for, really)

Comment: Yes, but I wanted a unique value for each year. Maybe add then a field with unique value instead of using Id, right?

Comment: The `IDENTITY` column handled by the database will do this - you don't need to do anything at all !

Comment: The answer you refer to *does* solve your problem. You just didn't do everything that's in it. That said, I agree with marc_s: don't do this. Don't use an identity column in the first place here.

Comment: Update: The answer I referred to earlier solved my problem, however, I also found the intended solution to the initial question. I used the method `ExecuteSqlInterpolated()` instead. And remove `dbo.`.

Comment: PS: I have added `_context.Database.OpenConnection();` before try{ }. it workes for me