# How to Customize index using code first?

Tags: indexing, ef-code-first

When creating classes using the code first approach, it will automatically generate CLUSTERED INDEX for the Key Property, and NON-CLUSTERED INDEX for the Foreign Key Property, BUT that's not always what we need, is there any way to customize that?

Comment: These might be very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098972/guid-comb-strategy-in-ef4-1-codefirst [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813190/how-to-stop-ef4-1-code-first-to-create-culstered-index-for-the-entity-pk/5815038#5815038